# Nuget and web.config formatting

Tags: nuget

As a standard at my company, all code documents use 4 spaces instead of tabs, and all tabs are replaced with 4 spaces as necessary. This all works fine and dandy. However, recently I discovered that any time Nuget performs an update to my web.config, the entire file is rewritten with 2 spaces in stead of 4 for each level of indent. This is really annoying, as it causes our VCS to think the entire file has changed when only a few lines actually have. Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: Yeah, this is a really annoying issue.  Having to constantly CTRL + K + D to get normal diffs is lame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not aware of any solutions to this. You should probably raise this on NuGet discussions: http://nuget.codeplex.com/discussions

Comment: @Chris Could you please link to that issue?  I can't find it.  I have this exact problem, except that I want to indent `web.config` with tabs instead of 2 spaces.

Comment: @Chris I'm wondering whether this is the issue you were referring to; please confirm: http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/1511

Answer (score 2):

Nuget has closed the issue without regard for impact on development concerns.

If you want your web.config to use something other than the default 2 spaces for each level of indentation, you can always go to

> Tools > Options > Text Editor > XML > Tabs

and change the settings there.

HTH.

Comment: This doesn't help at all. Did you even read the question / issue? We've already set the VS editor to use 4 spaces. The nuget transform resets it to 2 regardless.

Comment: Sure it does. No where in this thread was it mentioned that Nuget has abandoned the issue, and no where was a solution to the tabs/spaces addressed. CtrlK+CtrlD fixes the problem after a Nuget transform! Issue 'averted'.