# Prevent NuGet from modifying web.config?

Tags: web-config, nuget

I updated some nuget packages in my web project / solution.
However, this caused an update to my web.config file
and I'm pretty sure there are no changes.
Instead, nuget went and changed all my carriage return \ white space.

How do I prevent this from happening? The web.config needs to be formatted for easy human reading so that the deployment team can easily edit and change values.

Thanks!

Comment: This can depend on which package you installed, so can you add some details around what you installed and how it changed the file?

Answer (score 1):

Nuget modifies the web.config only if a package requires it. There was an open issue on formatting getting reset in such scenarios which I believe has been fixed. Here is the link -

http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/1511.

A similar issue is also discussed in the following thread about [nuget and web.config formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9828208/nuget-and-web-config-formatting)

Comment: It seems to be fixed in 2.3 version but it still breaks the formatting in 2.7.

Comment: @Ufuk Hacıoğulları - May be it makes sense to raise the issue again in that case.

Comment: On a side note, I don't think it is a good idea though to prevent nuget from modifying the web.config forcibly. This way the whole idea of seamless integration would be lost and the packages that need to modify wouldn't be able to modify the web.config [causing a lot of confusion].

Comment: NuGet breaks formatting instead of making minimal changes. That's also discussed in the issue.

Comment: Yes, and that is what the workitem tries to fix :) As you said earlier, it looks to be broken and should be raised again.

Comment: Almost 7 years later and NuGet **still** clobbers my `web.config` files. It's very annoying having to `git diff` them to see if it made any meaningful changes (usually to binding-redirects) and then doing `git reset` and copying+pasting any changes over.